# How can I extract all the 24 hour times from a string using regex?

Tags: javascript, regex

I want to extract all the 24 hour times inside a string.

An example of a string I want to extract the times from could be:

```
The image has been uploaded at 20:12 and viewed at 21:04 and later was deleted around 23:43
```

There are 3 times I want to extract from this example string:

- 20:12
- 21:04
- 23:34

I've tried this pattern:

```
^(([1-9]{1})|([0-1][0-9])|([1-2][0-3])):([0-5][0-9])$
```

But it only seems to validate if a time is correct.

Comment: Are you using some programming language? And no, you have anchors there which will only match if there's no other character in the string.

Comment: Yes, I'm using Javascript

Comment: Why not just use a simple one: `/\b\d{2}:\d{2}\b/g`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use

```js
let string = `The 30:1234 image has been uploaded at 20:12 and viewed at 21:04 and later was deleted around 23:43`;

let rx = /(\d+):(\d+)/g;

let match;

while ((match = rx.exec(string)) !== null) {
    if ((match[1] >= 0 && match[1] <= 24) && (match[2] >= 0 && match[2] <= 60)) {
        console.log(match[0]);
    }
}
```

Here you match any pattern `digits:digits` and validate them to fall in the correct ranges within `JavaScript` afterwards. Thus, e.g. `30:1234` will be ignored.

Comment: Much better to add code based validation like this with a simple regex ++